# How send the "value" attribute in a textinput tag to two managed beans in JSF

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to figure out how to send the same value="#{user.password}" to two managed beans How do I do it?

Comment: If you need to send it to two beans there is a big chance there is conceptually something wrong in your application. But if you really need to, send it to a 'controller' and have that populate both beans

Comment: Just set one property and let the both beans access it?